# How to append a dictionary as a value of a key in another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, scrapy

I have a dictionary:

```
accessToken = {'acces' : self.access , 'expires_in' :self.expires}
```

i want that it will be the value of **firstKey** in my second payload

i tried it

```
payload     =  {"firstKey" : json.dumps(accessToken) , "encodingVersion" : "1",
                "headerVersion" : "3" , "username" : username }
```

i want to have something like this

```
{'firstKey': {'acces' : self.access , 'expires_in' :self.expires},"encodingVersion" : "1",
  "headerVersion" : "3" , "username" : username }
```

**UPDATE 1**

and i tried

```
payload     =  {"firstKey" : accessToken , "encodingVersion" : "1",
                "headerVersion" : "3" , "username" : username }
```

and sent it in a form with FormRequest, but it was sent like

`headerVersion=3&username=usernameValue&encodingVersion=1&firstKey=selfaccess_value&firstKey=self_expires_value`

**UPDATE 2**

I send my query in **Scrapy** like this

```
yield  FormRequest(link, method="POST", formdata=payload
                          , callback=self.myFunction)
```

Comment: Simply use the `accsesToken` variable name as the value. Python will take care of the correct value substitution.

Comment: Try `payload['firstKey'] = accessToken`.

Comment: why do you use json.dumps() ??? it works directly as your requirement

Comment: looks like you use url query instead of proper data payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by changing

```
yield  FormRequest(link,headers=headers, formdata=payload, meta = meta ,  method="POST"
                          , callback=self.myFunction)
```

to

```
yield  FormRequest(link,headers=headers, body=str(payload), meta = meta ,  method="POST"
                          , callback=self.myFunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to the dictionary normally using the variable name `accessToken` as the value:

```
>>> accessToken = {'acces' : "self.access" , 'expires_in' :"self.expires"}
>>> payload     =  {"firstKey" : accessToken , "encodingVersion" : "1",
...                 "headerVersion" : "3" , "username" : "username" }
>>> 
>>> payload
{'headerVersion': '3', 'username': 'username', 'encodingVersion': '1', 'firstKey': {'acces': 'self.access', 'expires_in': 'self.expires'}}
>>>
```

Comment: No as i wrote in mu Update,  When i use what you said i have "firstKey" as a key of every element of second dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
{'firstKey': accessToken }
```

is perfectly ok. You can also add more keys and values if needed

Comment: it was not sent in FormRequest as i need

Comment: what is FormRequest? Be specific what library you using to sent what requests

Comment: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects

Comment: I have trouble to believe that data this way. May be try to change that self.access and self.expires to strings.

Comment: i answered my question, i resolved the problem by putting payload in body instead of formdata, and i change it to string instead of dictionary. before that i had error 500 (internal server error) i think that in the server side, it can't read dictionary or json, and it can read string

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
payload     =  {"firstKey" : accessToken , "encodingVersion" : "1",
                "headerVersion" : "3" , "username" : username }
```

In python, dictionary values can be of any type, including a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a key to the dictionary with a dictionary as its value, i.e.:

```
d1 = {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
d2 = {"key3": "val3", "key4": "val4"}

d1["key5"] = d2

print(d1)
{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key5": {"key3": "val3", "key4": "val4"}}
```